# Point object distorted because of proportions command

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, circles

I'm struggling with my first Tikz graph. I would like to plot a circle in the coordinate (20.48,0.6358) which corresponds to a minimum. However, given that the axis have different scales (`[x=0.15cm,y=6cm]`), the circle is distorted proportionally. Is there any way to avoid this and show a rounded circle (ideally with a letter "A" or something)?

*Bonus: Is it possible to put the y axis either in 2 lines or vertically along the y axis? The `\\` trick doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.15cm,y=6cm]

  \def\xmin{0}
  \def\xmax{57}
  \def\ymin{0}
  \def\ymax{1.12}

  % grid
  \draw[style=help lines, ystep=0.1, xstep=5, color=lightgray] (\xmin,\ymin) grid
  (\xmax,\ymax);

  % axes
  \draw[->] (\xmin,\ymin) -- (\xmax,\ymin) node[right] {\textit{Var2 (years)}};
  \draw[->] (\xmin,\ymin) -- (\xmin,\ymax) node[above] {\textit{Var 1 ideally in two \\ lines or vertically }};

  % xticks and yticks
  \foreach \x in {0,5,10,...,55}
    \node at (\x, \ymin) [below] {\x};
  \foreach \y in {0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1}
    \node at (\xmin,\y) [left] {\y};

  % generate and plot another a curve y = 0.1 x^2 + 2.5
  % this generates the files figure.parabola.gnuplot and figure.parabola.table 
  \draw[color=red, domain=\xmin:\xmax, line width=0.09cm] plot[id=parabola]
  function{0.7532*(1+(0.00034*x**2 - 0.01393*x))} node [right] {$y=0.00034\,x^2 + 0.01393\,x$};
  \draw [thick, dashed] (0,0.6358) -- (20.48,0.6358) -- (20.48,0);
  \draw [fill=black, black] (20.48,0.6358) circle [radius=0.08];

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: First Tikz graph]

Comment: (1) your MWE doesn't generate image which you show in question, (2) equation which you write in node is not the same as one, which is declared to be draw, (3) as far as I see, the point as you draw is exactly there, where you say that should be. If this is not right place, than function minimum is somewhere else.

Comment: @Zarko I just updated the code. Now it should reproduce the same image. The equation shown is 0.7532*(1+(0.00034*x**2 - 0.01393*x)). It is not important if the equation label doesn't include the 1+...
If I change the numbers in `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.15cm,y=6cm]` the picture would show differently. Do you know how to make the circle independent of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of changing `x` and `y` for the whole `tikzpicture`, do it inside an scope to keep its effect local; do all the things that should be affected bu the change in values inside the scope; draw the circle outside the scope:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\xmin{0}
  \def\xmax{57}
  \def\ymin{0}
  \def\ymax{1.12}
\begin{scope}[x=0.15cm,y=6cm]

  % grid
  \draw[style=help lines, ystep=0.1, xstep=5, color=lightgray] (\xmin,\ymin) grid
  (\xmax,\ymax);

  % axes
  \draw[->] (\xmin,\ymin) -- (\xmax,\ymin) node[right] {\textit{Var2 (years)}};
  \draw[->] (\xmin,\ymin) -- (\xmin,\ymax) 
  node[midway,rotate=90,yshift=28pt] {\textit{Var 1 ideally in two lines or vertically }}
  node[align=center,anchor=south] {\itshape Var 1 ideally in two \\ lines or vertically };

  % xticks and yticks
  \foreach \x in {0,5,10,...,55}
    \node at (\x, \ymin) [below] {\x};
  \foreach \y in {0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1}
    \node at (\xmin,\y) [left] {\y};

  % generate and plot another a curve y = 0.1 x^2 + 2.5
  % this generates the files figure.parabola.gnuplot and figure.parabola.table 
  \draw[color=red, domain=\xmin:\xmax, line width=0.09cm] plot[id=parabola]
  function{0.7532*(1+(0.00034*x**2 - 0.01393*x))} node [right] {$y=0.00034\,x^2 + 0.01393\,x$};
  \draw [thick, dashed] (0,0.6358) -- (20.48,0.6358) -- (20.48,0);
  \coordinate (aux) at (20.48,0.6358);
\end{scope}
  \draw [fill=black, black,] (aux) circle [radius=0.08];

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

### For the bonus points:

If you want to rotate the node label, you can use `rotate=<angle>` key to have the text rotated. If you want multiple line labels, you can use `text width=<length>` and/or `align=<option>` and replace `\textit` for `\itshape` (the former doesn't allow line breaks).

However, I'd suggest you to switch to [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.pgf/pkg/pgfplots) that was specifically designed to plot stuff; now your code is shorter and you have out-of-the-box features to customize your plots:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=left,
  xmin=0,
  xmax=57,
  ymin=0,
  ymax=1.05,
  xtick={0,5,...,55},
  ytick={0.1,0.2,...,1},
  xlabel={Var2 (years)},
  ylabel={Var 1 ideally in two lines or vertically},
  grid=both,
  width=10cm,
  height=7.5cm,
  clip=false
  ]
\addplot[red, domain=0:57,line width=3pt] {0.7532*(1+(0.00034*x^2 - 0.01393*x))} 
  node [right] {$y=0.00034\,x^2 + 0.01393\,x$};
  \draw [thick, dashed] (axis cs:0,0.6358) -- (axis cs:20.48,0.6358) -- (axis cs:20.48,0);
  \draw [fill=black, black,] (axis cs:20.48,0.6358) circle [radius=2pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From given MWE I can not reproduce image which is provided in question, therefore i change the code lines for drawing function:

```
\draw[domain=\xmin:\xmax, line width=0.9mm, red] 
     plot[id=parabola]   (\x,{0.7532*(0.00034*\x*\x - 0.01393*\x + 1)}) 
     node [right] {$y=0.00034\,x^2 + 0.01393\,x$};
```

which generate the following image:
[image]

In it I don't see any any distortion in minimum position. The MWE is:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz,
               ]{standalone}

    \begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.15cm,y=6cm]
  \def\xmin{0}
  \def\xmax{57}
  \def\ymin{0}
  \def\ymax{1.12}
% grid
  \draw[style=help lines, ystep=0.1, xstep=5, color=lightgray] 
        (\xmin,\ymin) grid  (\xmax,\ymax);
% axes
  \draw[->] (\xmin,\ymin) -- (\xmax,\ymin) node[right] {\textit{Var2 (years)}};
  \draw[->] (\xmin,\ymin) -- node[font=\itshape,above=7mm,align=center,sloped] 
                                {Var 1 ideally in two\\ 
                                 lines or vertically}               (\xmin,\ymax);
% xticks and yticks
  \foreach \x in {0,5,10,...,55}
    \node at (\x, \ymin) [below] {\x};
  \foreach \y in {0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1}
    \node at (\xmin,\y) [left] {\y};
% generate and plot another a curve y = 0.1 x^2 + 2.5
% this generates the files figure.parabola.gnuplot and figure.parabola.table
  \draw[domain=\xmin:\xmax, line width=0.9mm, red] 
    plot[id=parabola]   (\x,{0.7532*(0.00034*\x*\x - 0.01393*\x + 1)}) 
                        node [right] {$y=0.00034\,x^2 + 0.01393\,x$};

  \draw [thick, dashed] (0,0.6358) -| (20.48,0);
  \draw [fill=black]    (20.48,0.6358) circle (0.8mm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to work around that problem is to draw it as an ellipse, with different `x radius` and `y radius`. Multiplying the other unit vector gets you a circle. To allow for the line break, add the `align=<alignment>` key to the node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.15cm,y=6cm]

  \def\xmin{0}
  \def\xmax{57}
  \def\ymin{0}
  \def\ymax{1.12}

  % grid
  \draw[style=help lines, ystep=0.1, xstep=5, color=lightgray] (\xmin,\ymin) grid
  (\xmax,\ymax);

  % axes
  \draw[->] (\xmin,\ymin) -- (\xmax,\ymin) node[right] {\textit{Var2 (years)}};
  \draw[->] (\xmin,\ymin) -- (\xmin,\ymax) node[above,align=center] {\textit{Var 1 ideally in two} \\ \textit{lines or vertically }};

  % xticks and yticks
  \foreach \x in {0,5,10,...,55}
    \node at (\x, \ymin) [below] {\x};
  \foreach \y in {0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1}
    \node at (\xmin,\y) [left] {\y};

  % generate and plot another a curve y = 0.1 x^2 + 2.5
  % this generates the files figure.parabola.gnuplot and figure.parabola.table 
  \draw[color=red, domain=\xmin:\xmax, line width=0.09cm] plot[id=parabola]
  function{0.7532*(1+(0.00034*x**2 - 0.01393*x))} node [right] {$y=0.00034\,x^2 + 0.01393\,x$};
  \draw [thick, dashed] (0,0.6358) -- (20.48,0.6358) -- (20.48,0);
  \draw [fill=black, black] (20.48,0.6358) circle [x radius=0.08*6,y radius=0.08*0.15];

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

That said, have you considered `pgfplots`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   ylabel={var 1 vertically},
   xlabel={var 2},
   every axis label/.append style={font=\itshape},
   grid,
   domain=0:57,
   ymin=0,ymax=1.2,
   axis lines=left,
   ytick={0,0.1,...,1.2},
   xtick={0,5,...,55},
   clip=false
]

  \addplot [red] {0.7532*(1+(0.00034*x^2 - 0.01393*x))} node [right] {$y=0.00034\,x^2 + 0.01393\,x$};
  \draw [thick, dashed] (0,0.6358) -- (20.48,0.6358) coordinate(minimum) -- (20.48,0);
\end{axis}
  \draw [fill=black, black] (minimum) circle [radius=0.08];
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]